# Provisioning profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.default-data-protection entitlement

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications

When I'm enabling push notifications in project, I am receiving the following compiler error:

`Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile:" doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.default-data-protection entitlement.`

When I remove this key from the .entitlements file, the error is gone, and push notifications are working, at least according to what i'm noticing at this moment.

So I was wondering is this key solely a security measure as described here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements or perhaps does this have any impact on functionality of APNS as well?